# How to add another option to set object origin hotkey

Tags: shortcut, origin

I have a script that sets the objects origin to the center and the lowest point in z of the object.

Everything works and I have it in my own custom tab under tools.

But how can I add it to the shortcut ctrl+shift+alt+c?

I have been able to add it other places (like the add mesh menu, although obviously not where I need it) but I cannot find any info on adding something to the set object origin menu.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

To adjust an existing menu, you need to start by finding the python class name of the existing menu you want to alter. You then create a function that uses the same argument list as a classes draw method and append it to the menu in [`bpy.types`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.html). You can see an example of this in the [add object template script](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/addon_add_object.py;5ea729845d8b11ecd0d1f200fc7b23e6461b97bb$63).

In the case of the set origin operator, the menu is created by the operator, it is based on an enum that appears to only exist in the [C source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/object/object_transform.c;5ea729845d8b11ecd0d1f200fc7b23e6461b97bb$1097) and isn't exposed to python, meaning it doesn't appear to be adjustable,

If you can't find the name of the menu, then you can create a replacement menu yourself. You would then create a shortcut that calls your menu and disable the original shortcut.

An example addon can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/sambler/d3c7f40854f1c2ecb510a49bebcb1ece).